# Can I use LQFP on same TQFP footprint?

Tags: pcb, packages, replacement, tqfp

I need to order a 32 pin LQFP chip and replace it with another 32 pin TQFP chip so is it ok to replace it or it won't be compatible?

The chip is an STM8S003K3 MCU

Comment: What're the package dimensions? Does the datasheet recommended footprint line up well enough?

Comment: both of them are 7*7mm

Comment: The question edit was rolled back because the information is required to have the accepted ansewr make sense. Please do not edit the question in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to the datasheet, it does not appear to be offered by ST in a TQFP package, only 0.8mm pitch LQFP32 in 32-pins.

So whatever it is that you are potentially ordering is either not ST or there is an error of some kind. I suggest you get to the bottom of it before placing an order.

Comment: I guess so, but in general is it ok to use the LQFP instead of TQFP package? (I edited the question so we can speak in gerneral)

Comment: You need to look at the drawing of the package in the datasheet and see if it is compatible. If only the height is different it could well be compatible. If the pitch or body size is different..

Comment: Thanks mate, I had checked it and yes it is compatible.